# How to show $T(p(x))=xp(x)$ from $V$ to $V$ is either injective or surjective if $V=P(R)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, linear-transformations

My first question is that can we assume that the two vector spaces $V$ have the same dimension??

If so, we can just prove injectivity.

My first method is let $p(x)\in \ker T$, then $T(p(x))=0$. Then $xp(x)=0$. But I don't know if $x$ is assumed to be not $0.$ If it's assumed that $x\ne 0$, then we easily see $p(x)=0$.

My second method is using matrix representation (which i don't know if that's valid since we don't know that dimension of $P(R)$). If we suppose $p(x)$ has degree of $n+1$, then we can write it as $a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n$. Then $xp(x)=a_0x+a_1x^2+...+a_nx^{n+1}$. The matrix has a row of $0$, so this outcome is contradicting my first method.

Could someone clear my mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p(x)\in\text{Ker}\,(T)$, then $xp(x)\equiv 0$, i.e., $xp(x)$ is the zero polynomial. Once $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is a domain, we must have $p(x)\equiv0$ once $x$ is not the zero polynomial. So $T$ is injective. Now observe that if $\text{deg}\,(p(x))=d$ then $\text{deg}\,(T(p(x)))=d+1$. So we see that $T(\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}))=\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\setminus\mathbb{R}$, so you have the take $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\setminus\mathbb{R}$ as the domain of $T$ in order for it to be surjective.